# iOS event/notification for network using CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver

Tags: iphone, notifications, jailbreak

I want to detect when network data (Wifi, 3G) is turn on/off.
I detected the net work notification with "kCTRegistrationStatusChangedNotification"

Comment: Are you asking to detect when, for example, the 3G network is available/connected, or when the user decides to turn it on or off (with Settings, or an SBSettings toggle)?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: I listen the notify with CTTelephonyAddObbserver
I want to detect when NETWORK (Both 3G and Wifi) are availabel or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code provided by APPLE itself to check internet connection availability with WiFi as well as any other option like Wireless Wide Area Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.

Try integration of that code in your application and check. Let me know in case of any problem integrating code, we will work together to get your problem resolved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to build DYLIB, a Mobile Substrate Plugin, "Reachability" works with that

Comment: I Used Reachability in my app with User Interface, it work perfectly. 
But on my "dylib" project, some error but I don't know why:
"_SCNetWorkReachabilitySetCallBack", reference from: -Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o .... and something like that.

Comment: @user1561904, did you **link** your own dylib project with the SystemConfiguration.framework?

Comment: @user1561904 Reachability only helps to know status of available network it doesn't allow turn on/off, and error you said is definitely sounds like frame is missing as Nate has said.